# Run multiple R scripts with exiting/restarting in between on Linux

Tags: r, bash, rscript

I have a series of R scripts for doing the multiple steps of data
analysis that I require. Some of these take a very long time and create really
large objects. I've noticed that if I just source all of them in a row (via a `main.R` script), the
processing for later steps takes much longer than if I source one script, save
what I need, and restart R for the next step (loading the data I need).

I was wondering if there was a
way, via `Rscript` or a `Bash` script perhaps, that I could carry this out.
There would need to be objects that persist for the first 2 scripts (which load
my external data and create the objects that will be used for all further
steps). I suppose I could also just save those and load them in further scripts.

(I would also like to pass a number of named arguments to this script, which I think I can find on other SO posts and can use something like `optparse`.)

So, the script would look something like this, I think:

```
#! /bin/bash
Rscript 01_load.R  # Objects would persist, ideally
Rscript 02_create_graphs.R  # Objects would persist, ideally
Rscript 03_random_graphs.R  # contains code to save objects
#exit R
Rscript 04_permutation_analysis.R  # would have to contain code to load data
#exit
```

And so on. Is there a solution to this? I'm using `R 3.2.2` on 64-bit CentOS 6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

it sounds you should do some manual housekeeping between (or within) your steps by using `gc()` and maybe also `rm()`. For more details see `help(gc)` and `help(rm)`.

So instead of exit R and restart it again you could do:

```
rm(list = ls())
gc()
```

But please note: `rm(list = ls())` would throw away all your objects. Better you create a suitable list of objects you really want to throw away and pass this list to `rm()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that I have tried using `gc()`. While it helps in terms of memory management, it doesn't seem to get things as fast as running from a clean session. Although I haven't done extensive testing on this.